# how set value in dictionary when content a dictionary and class

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I defined the variable below:

```
Dictionary<clssMenu_Item, Dictionary<clssMenu_Item, List<clssMenu_Item>>> dicMenu =
        new Dictionary<clssMenu_Item, Dictionary<clssMenu_Item, List<clssMenu_Item>>>();
```

The type `clssMenu_Item` is defined as:

```
class clssMenu_Item
{
    public string name;
    public string text;
}
```

I have a string (I call `strKey`) already assigned to the `text` property of `clssMenu_Item` inside `dicMenu`.  It's clear `text` is part of `key`.  I want to search `dicMenu` to find `value` of `strKey` in all over of dictionary such as its sub. I don't know how can get this value?!

this method calculates the `key` of the dictionary:

```
private  List<clssMenu_Item> GetFormButtons(Form form)
{
    List<clssMenu_Item> ListBtn = new List<clssMenu_Item>();
    foreach (Control c in GetAllControls<Button>(form))
    {
        int btnIndex= c.Name.IndexOf("btn");
        if (btnIndex != 0) // find all of the determined buttons
        {
            clssMenu_Item objBtn = new clssMenu_Item();
            objBtn.name = c.Name.ToString();
            objBtn.text = c.Text;

            ListBtn.Add(objBtn);
        }
    }
    return ListBtn;   
}
```

here is how I populate the key:

```
foreach (var k in objH.mainForm) //fill dicMenu
{
    dicMenu.Add(k,null);
}
```

The reason that I'm using a nested dictionary is that this tree has only 3 levels.  Each `clssMenu_Item`s has a group of children like itself `type`.  `dictionary` was my solution to save them.

**problem:**
now I wanna fill value of keys by below code:

```
Dictionary<clssMenu_Item, List<clssMenu_Item>> d2 = new Dictionary<clssMenu_Item, List<clssMenu_Item>>();
    clssMenu_Item k = new clssMenu_Item();
    k.text = strKey;
    foreach(var prp in dicMenu.Keys) //we should fill all of the variables in class
    {
        if (prp.text == strKey)
        { k.name = prp.name; break; }
    }
    d2= dicMenu[k]; //assign value of key
```

I dont know why I have error on `d2= dicMenu[k];` said `k` is not in `DicMenu`, although I debug this block. we have `k` in `DicMenu` :( I dont know what should I do?!
is there other way to create a tree?

Comment: I would surely help if i understood :)

Comment: please understand me, it's really hard for me to explain more. because `dicMenu` is complex. please read exactly again word by word, then let me know which part need more info. thank u <3

Comment: There are two problems with your current Dictionary declaration that will prevent you getting what you're asking for. #1) The key of dicMenu are clssMenu_Item objects. That means you can only lookup into that dictionary using the same key objects. The value of the clssMenu_Item name and text members will be irrelevant. You'd have to redefine Equals for that class. Even if you do that, you run into problem #2) Keying on an object but only wanting to lookup using a single member of that object is going to cause grief. I'd rethink how you declare your Dictionary to match how you wish to access it

Comment: Adding to my previous comment...unless you want to just enumerate and test every element of the dictionary.

Comment: Why not a simple dictionary with the text property as the key and the class as the value?  `Dictionary<string, clssMenu_Item> dicMenu = new Dictionary<string, clssMenu_Item>();`  What requirements are driving you to use (or believe you need to use) nested dictionaries?

Comment: @varocarbas dear varocarbas! you're right!! now what should i do?!

Comment: @Tim yes I require nested dictionary

Comment: @varocarbas please give me solution, if u could... I assign `text` and `name` then add it to `dicMenu`

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you need a nested dictionary?  Can you also let us know what the requirements are?  It's possible there are easier solutions than a nested dictionary.

Comment: @varocarbas why did u delete your posts and comments?! I didn't take a note from your post :(